# Calculate the time difference between two hh:mm columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading some data from an csv file where the datatype of the two columns are in hh:mm format. Here is an example:

```
Start   End
11:15   15:00
22:30   2:00
```

In the above example, the End in the 2nd row happens in the next day. I am trying to get the time difference between these two columns in the most efficient way as the dataset is huge. Is there any good pythonic way for doing this? Also, since there is no date, and some Ends happen in the next I get wrong result when I calculate the diff.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['End'])-pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
0     0 days 03:45:00
1     0 days 03:00:00
2   -1 days +03:30:00
```

Comment: Please when dealing when DF, give a reproducible (with data) example

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the expected output.

Comment: @azro slipped my mind. thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the technique `(a+x)%x` with a `timedelta` of 24h (or 1d, same)

- the `+ timedelta(hours=24)` makes all values becomes positive
- the `% timedelta(hours=24)` makes the ones above `24h` back of `24h`

```
df['duration'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['End']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Start']) + timedelta(hours=24)) \
                 % timedelta(hours=24)
```

Gives

```
   Start      End            duration
0  11:15    15:00     0 days 03:45:00
1  22:30     2:00     0 days 03:30:00
```